# Get exception from Facade constructor when resolving controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, unity-container, facade

I have simple controller with one dependency

```
public TestController(ITestFacade testFacade)
{
    _testFacade = testFacade;
}
```

and simple facade

```
public class TestFacade : ITestFacade
{
    public TestFacade()
    {
        throw new Exception("Test");
    }
}
```

I have Unity resolver and registration

```
public static void RegisterDependencies(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<ITestFacade, TestFacade>();
}
```

UnityResolver is common as found everywhere. Nothing custom.

```
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    try
    {
        return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
    }
    catch (ResolutionFailedException)
    {
        // Here in one of Inner Exceptions is my Facade exception, but I want to get it later

        return null;
    }
}
```

Please consider this as test scenario. Facade in constructor should fail for any reason. It is not important now.

Running application results in exception:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TestController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

Ok, this is because of error in constructor of Facade when resolver is not able to get instance and activator in controller failed.

**My question is** - is there any way how to catch this exception in IHttpControllerActivator or somewhere?
I can try catch code in Facade constructor and log it somehow, but why this exception is ignored after resolver.

Comment: did you call DependencyResolver.SetResolver when configuring unity?

Comment: THis is not MVC, so no. But I have no problem in resolving or Unity. It works fine. I'm just looking for info how to get this test exception, because what I found, it is swallowed somewhere and resolver shows generic top level exception. But I'm missing the true reason, why controller exception occures.

Comment: Hmm, no one knows?